# Need a way for two separate Kinetic objects to "talk" with eachother in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have two objects programmatically generated using a three dimensional array of coordinates. The first dimension being 'grid' table, the second dimension being the 'row' of the grid and the third dimension being the column location in that row. (I only mention the way the array is set up for any insight that might be helpful).

Using a for loop and the standard methods of regular polygon generation using the Kinetic library I create a number of triangles in a visual grid. Each triangle is it's own object and which I want to animate independently.

My problem is: If I want to string an animation to a triangle's neighbor, I am unsure of how to reference which triangles are the neighbors of the 'origin' triangle (without potentially creating a 'grid ID' attribute within each triangle object and cross referencing using the triangle's own grid ID) and then once the objects are identified, push the animation tween to it's neighbors.

Each triangle its named exactly the same in memory reference so calling child attribute function of x triangle will not work I need a way to get object by ID or by some other attribute and make that object run it's function.

Here is an example of one of the Kinetic js objects:

```
            var tri = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                sides: 3,
                radius: 15,
                rotation: z,
                fillRed: 17,
                fillGreen: 17,
                fillBlue: 17,
                closed: true,
                shadowColor: '#5febff',
                shadowBlur: 5,
                shadowOpacity: 0.18
            });
```

I create the grid from a seperate array like so:

```
        function createTri(x, y, z) {
            var tri = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                sides: 3,
                radius: 15,
                rotation: z,
                fillRed: 17,
                fillGreen: 17,
                fillBlue: 17,
                closed: true,
                shadowColor: '#5febff',
                shadowBlur: 5,
                shadowOpacity: 0.18
            });


            layer.add(tri);

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < pax.length; i++){
            for (var j = 0; j < pax[i].length; j++){
                createTri(pax[i][j][0],pax[i][j][1],pax[i][j][2]); //Reads the two coordinates and the orientation located in the grid based on index location and then calls the function createTri to create each triangle in the grid.
            };
        }
```

If I need to explain my intentions further, I will happily clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [simple.js](http://simplejs.org/) and create objects with relations that associate them with one another.

e.g.

```
var Triangle = Simple.Model = function(options) {
  // add any attributes
  this.attributes = this.defaults || {};
}
```

And when you call createTri,

```
var tri = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({ ... });

var obj = new Triangle();
obj.polygon = tri;
obj.neighbors = [];
```

This is just an approach that I'd consider. Makes it easier to expand upon if you want to add more functionality to objects as well.

Comment: Might work, but is there any function that you know of that is something like a 'getObjectByAttributeValue()'? (kinda like getElementByID()) that would then let me call something like: getObjectByAttributeValue(valueCrossReference).callFunction ?

Comment: If you mean an HTML element, [yes](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: I didnt mean using HTML... I was using getElementByID as an allegorical reference for what Im trying to do

Comment: I mean you can make structures to be able to search on within simple.js, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.